# What are binary types in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hadoop - The Definitive Guide says

> If you want to log binary types, plain text isn’t a suitable format.

My Questions is 1. Why not? 2. What are binary types?

and further:

> Hadoop’s  SequenceFileclass fits the bill in this situation, providing
>   a persistent data structure for binary key-value pairs. To use it as a
>   logfile format, you would choose a key, such as timestamp represented
>   by a LongWritable, and the value is a Writable that represents the
>   quantity being logged.

Why text file can't be used and sequence file is required?

Answer (score 0):

On the same page, it was quoted that:

> For some applications, you need a specialized data structure to hold your data. For doing
>   MapReduce-based processing, putting each blob of binary data into its own file doesn’t
>   scale, so Hadoop developed a number of higher-level containers for these situations.

e.g. Assume that you are uploading images in facebook and you have to remove duplicate images. You can't store image in textformat. What you can do : get MD5SUM of image file and if MD5SUM already exists in the system, just discard insertion of duplicate image. In your text file, you can simply have "**Date**:" and "**Number of images uploaded**". Image can be stored out side of HDFS system like CDN network or at some other web server